# How can I get form data to php via jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have some validation code something like this -

```
     if ($('#address').val()) {
            if ($('#address').val().length > 60 || $('#address').val().length < 5)  { 
                errorMessage  += "Length of Your Address must be between 5 and 60.\n";
                valid = false;
          } else {
                var rege = /^[a-zA-Z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i;
                if(!rege.test($('#address').val())){ 
                         errorMessage  += "Please enter Valid Address.\n";
                         valid = false;
                } else {
                     var address = $('#address').val();
                     //alert ('My address is : ' + address);
                }
          } 
     } else { 
          errorMessage += "please enter your address\n";
          valid = false;
     }
```

My problem is how I get this value to php. My value have here -  `var address = $('#address').val();`

I need to check this value again in PHP and need to echo the value on the same page.

I use it something like this -

```
     if( !valid && errorMessage.length > 0){
          alert(errorMessage);
     } else {
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
                url: "demo2.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
                data: {
                     myname: name,
                     myaddress: address,
                     myemail: email
                }
        });    


     }
```

demo2.php page is the same page which my form have.

Above of my page I tried to print $_POST array but nothing display there.

```
echo '<pre>', print_r( $_POST).'</pre>';
```

Hope someone will help me. 
Thank you.

Comment: Does your echo really have a , after the first '<pre>' or did you make a typo?

Comment: Try to debug the AJAX call using the network tab on the console. There you can see if the params are being sent with the request or not.

Comment: Yes I have a , after the first

Comment: I tried it using network tab. It seems data is sending to the server. under `post` tab there, display data something like this - `myaddress dfklsjfls
myemail fsdfljfslf@gmail.com
myname Tharanga`

Comment: On the response tab under network tab - display data something like this - `Array
(
    [myname] => Tharanga 
    [myaddress] => fsdfljfslf
    [myemail] => fsdfljfslf@gmail.com
)`

Comment: With the same page do you mean the one that sends the Ajax? Shouldn't you add something like `dataType:'json', success: function (a){ alert(a[0]); }` in your ajax call and `echo json_encode(array(0=>'<pre>'.print_r( $_POST).'</pre>'));` in your php?

Comment: I don't know any other way to display some information through AJAX

Comment: @Dheed I tried but not working.

Answer (score 0):

First put a check in demo2.php for if POST is set

```
if( isset($_POST['myaddress']) ) {
  // your echo statement here
}
```

Then you just need to add some code to the jquery handle the response.

```
if( !valid && errorMessage.length > 0){
  alert(errorMessage);
} else {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
    url: "demo2.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
    data: {
      myname: name,
      myaddress: address,
      myemail: email
    }
  }).done(function(response) {
    $('#address-display-div').html(response);
  });
}
```

replacing `#address-display-div` with whatever selector you're going to display the address in.

Comment: n_i_c_K I have already tried it - `if (isset($_POST['myname'])) {
 $name = $_POST['myname'];
 echo $name;
}
` But its not luck for me

Comment: in the done function, can you try `console.log(response)` and check the console to see what you get?

Comment: I can not get anything in the cosole

Answer (score 0):

Request page:

```
var request =$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "demo2.php",
        data: {myname: name,myaddress: address,myemail: email}
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (a) {
            alert(a[0]);
        }
    }); 
    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){alert('Ajax Error: '+ textStatus);});
```

And in your php file:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['myname']) && isset($_POST['myaddress']) && isset($_POST['myemail'])){
        [do your stuff]
        echo json_encode(array(0=>'<pre>'.print_r( $_POST,true).'</pre>'));
    }
    else
        echo json_encode(array(0=>'Missed Variable'));
    exit();
?>
```

Otherwise can you also post your php page?

Comment: I use same page for my PHP coding, here it is - demo2.php

Comment: @TNK try `print_r($_POST,true)`

Comment: @TNK also add the php at the very beginning of the page

Comment: checked it. nothing happen

Comment: @TNK One last try: put before the `echo` statement `file_put_contents('array',print_r($_POST,true));` and check if in the same folder of demo2.php there a file called array and check it's content

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35382/discussion-between-tnk-and-dheed)